# Exactly how persistent is localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have written an Android PhoneGap application that uses localStorage. As long as the user does not clear the localStorage themselves, is localStorage a persistent way to store data? Will the data last as long as the user doesn't delete it? My understanding is that it will persist, but I just want to make sure before releasing it. If this isn't so persistent, what else would be a good way to store data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. localStorage is persistent until user clears/disables it.

Comment: So as long as the person who downloads the app has localStorage enabled and doesn't clear it, the data will remain?

Comment: @areke yes. I dont know your application but as far i know localstorage is only for web. Just make some tests and make sure that all is working fine.

Comment: I have tested it by shutting down the phone and the data still persisted. I just did not know if it would be there in a month or year. From what i have heard, i think it will and am gonna leave it as is (unless someone figues out a huge downside to it).